# Hola quiero borrar cierto contenido de una carpeta

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

Tengo una duda simple.
He generado unos archivos en diferentes formatos (.csv, .txt, etc)

Necesito borrar algunos. En concreto **todos los ".csv"** y **los que terminan con "h+*.txt"** (siendo el * cualquier numero entero del 1 al 99).

He probado con esto:

```
for archivos in glob.glob((ruta_carpeta) + '*.csv')
   os.remove(archivos)
```

tambien he probado:

```
os.remove(ruta_carpeta+'\\'+'*.csv')
```

Pero no me funciona niguna
Alguna sugerencia
Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué significa que no te funciona? ¿Obtienes un error? ¿Cuál?

Comment: Para unir rutas de archivos te sugiero que uses `os.path.join("/ruta/al/projecto", "borrame.txt")` qué es mucho más portable y seguro que unir cadenas de esta forma `ruta_carpeta+'\\'+'*.csv'`. La documentación oficial (en inglés) la podés ver acá https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pruebe con estas lineas:

```
import os

files = os.listdir("C:\\path") # La ruta la copia tal cual del explorador y añade "\" entre carpetas. el ultimo queda libre sin "\\"

for name in files:
    if name.endswith(".csv"):
        print(name)
        os.remove("C:\\path\\%s" % name) # Igual se copia la ruta y se añade "\\%s" al final.
```

y para los txt:

```
import os

files = os.listdir("C:\\path")

for name in files:
    for i in range(100):
        if name.endswith("h" + str(i) + ".txt"):
            print(name)
            os.remove("C:\\path\\%s" % name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si suponemos que leemos las columnas así:

```
my @columnas = split /[,]/, $linea;
```

entonces, **eliminamos** las tres últimas columnas con:

```
splice @columnas, -3;
```